# IIS7.5 Application pools advanced settings - WAS reporting exceed job limit settings

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, application-pools

I am really lost with Application pools settings.

I am monitoring CPU utilization with resource monitor and/or windows task manager and the server hardly uses over 30% in one second. It seems that server and IIS can handle traffic and visits with ease.

Surprisingly, Even Viewer reports plenty of WAS 5025 events:

```
Application pool '%1' exceeded its job limit settings.
```

Application pools advanced setting:

**CPU**

```
Limit: 95
Limit Action: NoAction
Limit Interval (minutes): 5
```

There is no way that my IIS has 95% utilization for 5 minutes.

Or do I not understand these setting correctly?

Please advice

Answer (score 4):

As per my understanding the cpu limit should be configured in 1/1000ths of percents. See:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/cpu

So, setting the cpu limit to 95 configures IIS to use 0,095% as the maximum percentage of CPU time that the worker processes in the application pool are allowed to consume.

Comment: This is our understanding too. So instead of a limit of 95, it should be 95000.
If you look at the answer posted in this other discussion, you will see the sample pasted re-enforces this: https://forums.iis.net/t/1200826.aspx